# what is the difference between bitnami/kafka and confluentinc/cp-kafka

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

I want to create a dockerize project with Node.js and Kafka

So I read multiple tutorials, but some examples use [bitnami/kafka](https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/kafka/) with [bitnami/zookeeper](https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/zookeeper)

and some examples use [confluentinc/cp-kafka](https://hub.docker.com/r/confluentinc/cp-kafka/) with [confluentinc/cp-zookeeper](https://hub.docker.com/r/confluentinc/cp-zookeeper) in docker file.

**Note**:
And also I need to a UI for managing Apache Kafka, so based on [kafka-ui](https://github.com/provectus/kafka-ui), It uses `confluentinc/cp-kafka`, and I can't use it with `bitnami/kafka`.

What is the difference between `bitnami/kafka` and `confluentinc/cp-kafka` and which one is better to use?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`bitnami/kafka` just contains Apache Kafka. `confluentinc/cp-kafka` contains `Confluent Community` which is an additional platform built by Confluent which extends Apache Kafka.

You can check what the platform includes at https://www.confluent.io/product/confluent-platform/ (Features section, brown circles).

`kafka-ui` works with Apache Kafka so should work with any of the two images, although since it also serves as a UI for Kafka Connect and some of the Confluent platform components (schema registry), the examples use the `confluentinc` image. If you are not going to use these features, any docker image will work just fine.

Comment: Confluent containers such as schema registry and ksql also work with bitnami container.